# best xml format for store it in sql server database

Tags: sql-server, xml, entity-framework

I have a workflow in xml format like this:

```
...
<workflow>
  <tasks>
    <task type="start" id="Task_038517r" name="addRequest">
      <form id="Form_3y245d1"/>      
    </task>
    ...
    <task type="final" id="Task_1sytah6" name="confirmationRequest">
      <form id="Form_3y245d1"/>
    </task>
  </tasks> 
</workflow>
...
```

And I can change this to another format:

```
...
<workflow>
  <tasks>
    <task>
      <type>start</type>
      <id>Task_038517r</id>
      <name>addRequest</name>
      <form>
        <id>from_3jfu845</id>
      </form>
    </task>
    ...
    <task>
      <type>final</type>
      <id>Task_1sytah6</id>
      <name>confirmationRequest</name>
      <form>
        <id>form_3y245d1</id>
      </form>
    </task>
  </tasks>
</workflow>
...
```

I need to store this xml in workflowXML field. workflowXML is filed of workflow  sql server table. I need to get value of attributes using `entityframework` in web application.The first format is less volume. The second format has better structure.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain which method is better.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the answer of your question is hidden in the answer of "where to use it" . If you are going to parse and only read for id, name, etc and query database tables with these data, then you can even store it in a relational table instead of storing as XML.

Comment: Thanks for comment.I know I can do it but  I need to store it in xml format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage of the attribute oriented storage is that Each value **belongs** to the given element and it cannot exist twice.

If humans' readability is of any importance, the second format might be easier to be read (you call it *better structure*), but - to be honest - this should not bother you. XML is - in most cases - read by a machine. Attributes are closely bound to their elements.

As your data is probably generated, you should not have to bother about a (possible) duplication of a sub-element either, which might break your data.

So, my final statement would be it is somehow your personal taste. I'd prefer the attributes

Answer (score -1):

I think you will get attributes value of xml nodes using entityframework. Then you have to read about linq to xml and use it in this way. So I think the first format shows that can be done.
visit this links:

[how to get Attribute Value using linq to xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539897/how-to-get-attribute-value-using-linq-to-xml)

[Linq to XML simple get attribute from node statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987223/linq-to-xml-simple-get-attribute-from-node-statement)